# How to remove event listeners in Firefox debugger?

Tags: event-listener, firefox-developer-tools

Firefox has a feature in debugger that lists events for nodes - [here's a help article for it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Page_Inspector/How_to/Examine_event_listeners).

[image: image description]

For unclear reasons, I can't find a way to remove any of those listeners. How do I do that?

Comment: is there still no easy answer to this?

Comment: No, it's just recently been a year since  I asked it, but still no answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The same feature is there from the inspector in Chrome, but as you say not in (newish) DevTools in Firefox.

Before DevTools, it was there in Firebug ([screenshot](https://bug1226637.bmoattachments.org/attachment.cgi?id=8690141)), but the [issue to port it across](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1226637) has been open for 3 years.

Comment: They are tracking the issue here now: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1492497

Answer (score 11):

It seems that right-clicking the element in the inspector, choosing "Edit as HTML" and modifying the html code (even as slighltly as adding a space after the code) makes the listener go away

Comment: That only works for listeners assigned through HTML attribute, which is not very common way of assigning them.

Comment: I misread the answer, sorry. This method works indeed, but it removes all listeners and breaks any refferences to the DOM object.

Comment: I can confirm that on Firefox Developer Edition this works for JS assigned Event Listeners.

Comment: doesn't work for events attached to `html` tag

Answer (score 2):

The only workaround I've discovered, is to disable JavaScript altogether. You can do that in the "Debugger" tab, in the debugger settings to the right. Unfortunately that causes the page reload.